# Using different proxy on each request

Tags: http, go, proxy

As far as it is my understanding, the only way I can set a proxy for a request is to assign it to a client and then use that for a request. However, I also understand I should reuse the clients for my requests. Is there any way to individually assign proxies for each request whilst using the same client? Or any way to efficiently do a collection of requests with a different proxy for each request?

Comment: What have you tried to set proxies?

Comment: tried assigning a proxy within a transport and then including that when I initialise a client. Then the proxy will be used within the requests issued by that client. I'm not aware of any other ways to achieve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating of http.Client is not so expensive - its just a struct allocation that can be done for each request.

You should create http.Client and transport objects yourself and set proxy directly there.

```
proxyUrl, err := url.Parse("http://127.0.0.1:123")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
myClient := &http.Client{Transport: &http.Transport{Proxy: http.ProxyURL(proxyUrl)}}
myClient.Get("http://www.google.com/")
```

Tere is the other posibility to use always the same client with different proxies:

http.ProxyURL call from the first example is function:

```
// ProxyURL returns a proxy function (for use in a Transport)
// that always returns the same URL.
func ProxyURL(fixedURL *url.URL) func(*Request) (*url.URL, error) {
    return func(*Request) (*url.URL, error) {
        return fixedURL, nil
    }
}
```

You can extend it and chose proxy based on the information from request or implement some other logic.

**UPD**: here is implementation how to use ProxyUrl with only one Client. But overehead of changing context is comparable with overhead on creating a client. I would use the first scenario.

// We must write our own Get (or some other) request and add somewere the info that this is a proxy request. You can do it via context of request.

```
func GetWithProxy(c *http.Client,proxyUrl *url.URL, url string) (resp *http.Response, err error) {
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    if proxyUrl != nil {
        req = req.WithContext(context.WithValue(context.Background(),"proxy",proxyUrl))
    }

    return c.Do(req)
}
```

// Organize client that can use this information:

```
proxyUrl, err := url.Parse("http://127.0.0.1:123")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

myClient := &http.Client{Transport: &http.Transport{Proxy: func(req *http.Request) (*url.URL, error) {
    currentProxy,_ := req.Context().Value("proxy").(*url.URL)
    return currentProxy, nil
}}}
```

Use it:

```
GetWithProxy(myClient,nil,"http://www.google.com/")
GetWithProxy(myClient,proxyUrl,"http://www.google.com/")
```

Comment: So you're saying that it wouldn't actually be too costly to create a new client for each request I make, correct? That's good to hear. Will look into extending the method you've given as well, thanks :)

Comment: @JordanAllen: Yes - client its just struct with 4 fields . Transport is the interface - http.Transport is abit more than client itself - if you want you can preapre it for each proxy but actually it does not worth .

Comment: Amazing answer. Thank you, given me a lot of options and a lot of help understanding my options. Appreciate it!

Comment: Never create an `http.Transport` for each request (though I can't tell if that's what you're recommending or not). Not reusing the transport will leak open connections.

Comment: @JimB: You are right - Transport can keep connection open.